# How to add Security Headers to Custom Error Page of Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I would like to add Security Headers like "x-xss-protection" when custom error page responded from cloudfront.

Is there any way or documents to solve this problem?

Comment: What is Cloudfront hooked up to? S3 static website?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at a viewer response Lambda@Edge; adding custom headers to the response is a perfect use for a viewer-response Lambda@Edge. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-overriding-response-header

Comment: I'm encountering a similar problem where I want to re-direct a request for an unknown url such as https://example.com/.unknown/ to index.html. I am using a cloudfront error page to re-direct to /index.html but I notice this is being served directly from S3 and does not have the usual security headers applied by @lambda edge. There is probably a better way around this than the custom error page.